# Json_encode data using JSON.parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

**PHP file**

```
<?php
    include"connection.php";
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    // echo $id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $json_res=array();
    $json_res = array('user'=>($row));
    echo json_encode($json_res);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

**JavaScript file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadup(str){

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            // var json = '{"user":[{"id":"45","name":"dfgMohan","loc":"Cherthala","dist":"Alappuzha","phone":"456","email":"fgdfgh@gmail.c","gender":"male","proofid":"2","sslc":"SSLC","plus2":"PLUS 2","degree":"DEGREE","pg":""}]}';

            var x=xmlhttp.responseText;                    

            var json1=JSON.parse(x);
            alert(json1.user[0].id);
            alert(json1.user[0].name);

            document.getElementById("myd").innerHTML=json1;
        }
    } 

    xmlhttp.open("GET","plain.php?edit="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Why I cant alert this?

```
alert(json1.user[0].id);
alert(json1.user[0].name);
```

When I try to alert it, no alert message shown.

When I alert some message, it is shown before parsing code then after it not executing. The code is stuck on parse code line. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: show output of   echo json_encode($json_res);

Comment: Change x to str. `var json1=JSON.parse(x);`

Comment: @ShailendraSharma


output of json_encode ($json_res)

{"user":{"id":"45","name":"Abi Mohan","loc":"Cherthala","dist":"kizhok","phone":"984312584","email":"radfrgdfhe@gmail.c","gender":"male","proofid":"2","sslc":"SSLC","plus2":"PLUS 2","degree":"DEGREE","pg":""}}

Comment: @aldrin27 -y i change x to str??? i need to print the Ajax response, str is used to pass the id to php for getting details of an id from my db

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include"connection.php";
$id = $_GET['edit'];
// echo $id;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE id=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$json_res = array();

array_push($json_res, $row);


echo json_encode($json_res);





$conn->close();
?>
```

javascript file contains

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function loadup(str) {

                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        //var json = '{"user":[{"id":"45","name":"Raj Mohan","loc":"Cherthala","dist":"Alappuzha","phone":"9846320121","email":"rajmohan6535@gmail.c","gender":"male","proofid":"2","sslc":"SSLC","plus2":"PLUS 2","degree":"DEGREE","pg":""}]}';

                        var x = xmlhttp.responseText;


                       var json1 = JSON.parse(x);

                       document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "ID : "+json1[0].id;
                       document.getElementById("myd").innerHTML = "NAME : "+json1[0].name;



                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "plain.php?edit=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        </script>
```

when we give respomce please sure about there is no html contains in that page of php file ...  even commented lines.. they will give with response and we cant parse the response text so be careful ... when we pass a response from php dnt add or comment any html contains in a php (server hitting page)

i think may u all can understand my answer ..if not well please kindly forgive me.. my communication is very low in english thats y ..

to check if the html contains included in responce u just alert the responce in javascript then its shows any html contains response then php have some html contains thats y we cant parse it .....